# How to combine two grid position in Java?

Tags: java, swing, form-layout

I want to know how do you combine or merge two grid position using Java grid layout. I am creating a basic java application using the java grid layout(0, 2) with my JFrame and java form components like JLabel and JButton. I want to combine the top two cells to displays my title in the center of the application.

Comment: It is not possible with a `GridLayout`, but you can use a `GridBagLayout` instead.

Comment: can I use multiple grid layout within a single java class?

Comment: Yes, each container (like `JFrame` or `JPanel`) has their own layout manager.

Comment: @Ryan, don't forget to "accept" and answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I displayed the title by putting have of the text in one grid position and the other half and the next grid position. This worked with grid layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GridBagLayout

```
/*
 * GridBagLayoutDemo.java is a 1.4 application that requires no other files.
 */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GridBagLayoutDemo {
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;
    final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
    final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
            pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }

        JButton button;
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        if (shouldFill) {
            //natural height, maximum width
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        }

        button = new JButton("Button 1");
        if (shouldWeightX) {
            c.weightx = 0.5;
        }
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("Button 2");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("Button 3");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");
        c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("5");
        c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
        c.weighty = 1.0;   //request any extra vertical space
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END; //bottom of space
        c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
        c.gridx = 1;       //aligned with button 2
        c.gridwidth = 2;   //2 columns wide
        c.gridy = 2;       //third row
        pane.add(button, c);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the above code Long Named Button 4 is spanned across 3 columns.
Reference:- [How to use GridBagLayout](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: This solution works, but I do not fully comprehend grid bag layout.

Comment: @Ryan `but I do not fully comprehend grid bag layout.`- well you haven't have time to read the tutorial in the 6 minutes since the answer was given and you replied. So take the time to read the tutorial. Then if you still don't understand you can ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

make your layout have 3 rows only and one column
Then in the first row add you title label
And in the second and third rows add a panel and set its layout to grid with 2 coulmns and one row

Comment: interesting solution.

Comment: If you found it helpful, please set the question as solved